# How to create a ragged array using vectors?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have been trying to create and print out a ragged array matrix using vectors in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int>> Matrix;

int main ()
{
    Matrix a(10);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) a[i].resize(i + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)
        {
            std::cout << a[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have "somewhat" succeeded...

Output of the code above is:

```
07143616-12660115513423912300-10982394020134798700
00-1098239402013479870001-109823940134239122
0001-1098239401342391220000
0000-1097584032139471475527143616-428591069134239123
000001917869114-2593786113423912500
000000-916064620134798900
0000000691419256-9160646134239124
00000000-59492295201347988
0000000001684957527
0000000000
```

And I am looking for a triangle output like this:

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000000
00000000
000000000
0000000000
```

Can anyone point out the problem in this code, why can't I get a nicely printed triangle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop has a simple logic error:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    // wrong:
    // for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++)

    // should be a[i].size()
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. The problem is that the limit of your inner loop is wrong, it should be `a[i].size()`, not `a.size()`. So you're accessing nonexistent elements in the shorter vectors.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)
    {
        std::cout << a[i][j];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I understand :)